# Hide pop out date in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Guys i am using jqGrid.

A column named `order date` is editable all the time so whenever the page loads a datepicker appears.

What i want to do is make it at first editable without poping out the datepicker, and the datepicker should appear onclick on the date field.

Is it possible to do that ?
[image]

so how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bug with the date picker
A work around would be to add this to your css.

```
#ui-datepicker-div { display: none; }
```

I believe this bug was fixed though? Which version of jqgrid and jquery.ui are you using?